# Why can I create an instance of a static variable?

Tags: swift, static, singleton, instance

I have a `class` that looks like this:

```
class A {
    var aString = ""
    static var staticString = ""
}
```

If I create an `instance` of `A` I can't access the `static` `property`:

```
var a = A()
a.staticString = "THIS GIVES AN ERROR"
```

However, if I create a direct `instance` to the `static` `variable` it works:

```
var a = A.staticString
a = "THIS WORKS"
```

The way I understand static variables is that you should only be able to access them directly like this: `A.staticString = "hello"`. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

What's more confusing (to me) is that I can create multiple `instances` with their own seperate values; that is the value doesn't remain `static`:

```
var a = A.staticString
a = "AAA"

var b = A.staticString
b = "BBB"
print(a) //prints AAA
print(b) //prints BBB
```

Isn't the whole point that a `static` variable should... remain static? In my head, both a and b should print BBB since `b = "BBB"` should have overwritten the first value assigned to it.

To make it even more confusing (to me), using a `singleton` does give me the result I expect:

```
class A {
    static let shared = A()
    var aString = ""
    static var staticString = ""
}
```

```
let instance1 = A.shared
instance1.aString = "A String"
        
let instance2 = A.shared
instance2.aString = "Another String"
        
print(instance1.aString, instance2.aString) //Both print "Another String"
```

Could some kind soul try to clear things up for me?

Comment: The variable remains static, you just copy it to `a` and `b`, they have nothing to do with the static variable, just two string varaibles.

Comment: *static* is not the same as *constant* (let).

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keyword in Swift does not mean the property is immutable/constant (unlike in C-based languages). `static` means the property is a **type property**, not an **instance property**, meaning that it is a property of the type itself, shared between all instances and not a property of each instance. For more information, read the [Type Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID264) section of the Swift language guide.

Constants/immutable properties are declared by `let`, while mutable ones by `var`.

You can set and get static vars by using the type name (`A` in your case).

```
A.staticString = "new"
A.staticString // "new"
```

If you create instances of the type, you can use `type(of:)` to get the meta-type (`A`), which you can use to access static properties

```
let a = A()
type(of: a).staticString // "new"
let anotherA = A()
type(of: anotherA).staticString  // "new"
```